# Redux React create initial state from API

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

How to define `initialState` from API?

***Actions***

```
import * as types from '../constants/ActionTypes'
import jquery from 'jquery'
import { apiRoot } from '../config.js'
import Immutable from 'immutable'
import Random from 'random-js'

export function fetchLentItemList() {
  return function(dispatch) {
    dispatch(fetchLentItems());
    jquery.get(`${apiRoot}/api/v1/something/`)
      .done((data) => {
        dispatch(fetchLentItems("success", Immutable.fromJS(data)))
      })
      .fail(() => {
        dispatch(fetchLentItems("error"))
      })
  }
}

export function fetchLentItems(status, locations = Immutable.List()) {
  return { type: types.FETCH_LENT_ITEMS, status, locations }
}
```

***Reducers***

```
import * as types from '../constants/ActionTypes'
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import Immutable from 'immutable'

const initialState = {
  initialLentItems: [],
  lentItems: [] 
}

function initialLentItems(state = initialState.initialLentItems, action) {
  // return state
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.FETCH_LENT_ITEMS:
      switch (action.status) {
        case 'success':
          return {
            initialLentItems: action.locations,
            lentItems: []
          }
        case 'error':
          return {
            initialLentItems: Immutable.List(),
            lentItems: []
          }
        default:
          return Object.assign({}, state, { isLoading: true })
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  initialLentItems
})

export default rootReducer;
```

In `reducers` if I defined my `initialState` like this, it works:

```
initialLentItems: Immutable.fromJS([
    {
      "lent_item_id": 5648,
      "vendor": "Vendor A",
      "product": "Product A",
      "variant": "Variant A",
    },
    {
      "lent_item_id": 5648,
      "vendor": "Vendor B",
      "product": "Product B",
      "variant": "Variant B",
    }
  ]),
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly does not work for you?

Comment: the list I want is not returned

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the `componentWillMount` of your Redux root element (the one that is wrapped by `Provider` and receives the store) you can dispatch the `fetchLentItems` function to set up your initial state.

Comment: If we take this approach, doesn't the root element become sort of a dumping ground for getting state for many different components? And aren't we getting data unnecessarily if a user never ends up going to many of the pages/components when using your site?